# No C++ pthread support in build farm?

Tags: linux, gcc, threads, rpmbuild, configure

I'm trying to get some code compiling in a build farm. When I build it on my development machine things go fine:

```
checking if C compiler and POSIX threads work as is... no
checking if C++ compiler and POSIX threads work as is... no
checking if C compiler and POSIX threads work with -Kthread... no
checking if C compiler and POSIX threads work with -kthread... no
checking if C compiler and POSIX threads work with -pthread... yes
checking if C++ compiler and POSIX threads work with -Kthread... no
checking if C++ compiler and POSIX threads work with -kthread... no
checking if C++ compiler and POSIX threads work with -pthread... yes
checking for pthread_mutexattr_setpshared... yes
checking for pthread_condattr_setpshared... yes
checking for PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK_NP... yes
checking for PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK... yes
checking for working POSIX threads package... yes
```

But when I give it to the build farm it fails to find a working compiler option to enable pthread support:

```
[   87s] checking if C compiler and POSIX threads work as is... no
[   87s] checking if C++ compiler and POSIX threads work as is... no
[   87s] checking if C compiler and POSIX threads work with -Kthread... no
[   87s] checking if C compiler and POSIX threads work with -kthread... no
[   87s] checking if C compiler and POSIX threads work with -pthread... yes
[   87s] checking if C++ compiler and POSIX threads work with -Kthread... no
[   87s] checking if C++ compiler and POSIX threads work with -kthread... no
[   87s] checking if C++ compiler and POSIX threads work with -pthread... no
[   87s] checking if C++ compiler and POSIX threads work with -pthreads... no
[   87s] checking if C++ compiler and POSIX threads work with -mt... no
[   87s] checking if C++ compiler and POSIX threads work with -mthreads... no
[   87s] checking if C++ compiler and POSIX threads work with -lpthreads... no
[   87s] checking if C++ compiler and POSIX threads work with -llthread... no
[   87s] checking if C++ compiler and POSIX threads work with -lpthread... no
[   87s] checking for pthread_mutexattr_setpshared... yes
[   87s] checking for pthread_condattr_setpshared... yes
[   87s] checking for PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK_NP... yes
[   87s] checking for PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK... yes
[   87s] checking for working POSIX threads package... no
[   87s] configure: WARNING: "*** POSIX threads are not"
[   87s] configure: WARNING: "*** available on your system "
[   87s] configure: error: "*** Can not continue"
```

The dev box and the buildfarm are using the same base OS -- the only difference is that the environment on the buildfarm is very minimal, only installing the packages required by the spec file on top of a small set of base OS packages.

I can't think of any "missing package" that would cause this behavior. glibc-* are installed on both.

Comment: "only installing the packages required by the spec " - obviously the specification file is missing a required package.  My suggest start putting on packages that don't exist on on the minimal installation until it works.

Comment: Try `yum install libxcb-devel` (I'm assuming yum because of rpmbuild)

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi - neither machine has libxcb-devel installed. Adding it to the build farm system doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: @Ramhound - Very well could be. I've been adding things, but I've exhausted everything that seems even remotely related. Same goes for the environment, which I haven't completely ruled out being the issue

Comment: `libglibXXX-dev` installed?  pkg-config?  Usually errors like this are X-dev related.  Find the associated -dev package to install.     Pull list of installed packages on your system, and on build farm system, compare?

Answer (score 0):

Actual credit / source : https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/509781-No-C-Pthread-support-inside-OBS by wolfi323

I encountered a similar problem while trying to configure [Open MPI 3] with:

```
./configure CC=gcc CXX=gcc FC=gfortran
```

wolfi323's answer on forums.opensuse implies that the **c++ compiler was not adequately specified**. I left the c/c++ compiler options blank:

```
./configure FC=gfortran
```

the configuration reported:

```
checking if C++ compiler and POSIX threads work with -Kthread... no
checking if C++ compiler and POSIX threads work with -kthread... no
checking if C++ compiler and POSIX threads work with -pthread... yes
```

and completed.

### Extra

Setting

```
CC=gcc CXX=g++
```

yielded the same/similar results as letting ./configure find the default compilers.